# What containers provide systemd aside from RHEL's UBI?

Tags: systemd, rhel, container

I have an application I must containerize and it has a dependency on systemd during installation I can't change. It **does not** need systemd to run, it just has to be there during install. So far, the only container I can find that has systemd baked in and is up to date is Red Hat's UBI, but it is very limited in what packages are available without a subscription.

Right row I'm working around this by using [Atomic's repo](http://www6.atomicorp.com/channels/atomic/centos/8/x86_64/RPMS/) and installing from there.

Is there another container that is currently maintained that offers sytsemd?

Comment: How does the app check that systemd is present? It might be easiest to just fake it ..

Comment: Unfortunately not that easy, it has a series of commands that set the app up to run on boot. Not worth reverse engineering and simulating all the functionality. Some of it is in a compiled JAR that would require me to go to another team and get them to update their source code to accommodate me which is more than I want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among others, Debian, Fedora, and Ubuntu all provide currently-maintained container base images with systemd available. For example,

```
FROM debian:11
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y systemd
```

or

```
FROM fedora:38
RUN dnf install -y systemd
```